# Resize image width in c# but not the height

Tags: c#, image, razor

How do you resize the width of a image in C# without resizing the height using image.resize()

When I do it this way:

```
image.Resize(width: 800, preserveAspectRatio: true,preventEnlarge:true);
```

This is the full code:

```
var imagePath = "";
var newFileName = "";
var imageThumbPath = "";
WebImage image = null;            
image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
if (image != null)
{
    newFileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
    imagePath = @"pages/"+newFileName;
    image.Resize(width:800, preserveAspectRatio:true, preventEnlarge:true);
    image.Save(@"~/images/" + imagePath);
    imageThumbPath = @"pages/thumbnail/"+newFileName;
    image.Resize(width: 150, height:150, preserveAspectRatio:true, preventEnlarge:true);
    image.Save(@"~/images/" + imageThumbPath);
}
```

I get this error message:

> No overload for method 'Resize' takes 3 arguments

Comment: Could you post more code? I mean, what is the type of your `image` object, definitions, how do you get it?

Comment: It sounds like you do *not* want to preserve the aspect ratio then.

Comment: The name of the method is `ResizeImage`, isnt is?

Comment: What is the Type of `image`?  I see no `System.Drawing.Image.Resize()` method.

Comment: seems the question is somehow linked from here : http://johndonnellyz.wordpress.com/tag/webimage/

Comment: Its for png and jpg images, I'm using Razor

Comment: Do you want the height to be determined automatically based on the aspect ratio?  Or are you trying to stretch the image, changing the width, but leaving the height at the original value?

Comment: @gilly3 yes I want the height resized automatically based on the aspect ratio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.resize(VS.111).aspx) is garbage, so I peeked at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/v2.1/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebImage.cs).  The logic they are using is to look at the values passed for height and width and compute aspect ratios for each comparing the new value to the current value.  Whichever value (height or width) has the greater aspect ratio gets its value computed from the other value.  Here's the [relevant snippet](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/v2.1/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebImage.cs#L871-L880):

```
double hRatio = (height * 100.0) / image.Height;
double wRatio = (width * 100.0) / image.Width;
if (hRatio > wRatio)
{
    height = (int)Math.Round((wRatio * image.Height) / 100);
}
else if (hRatio < wRatio)
{
    width = (int)Math.Round((hRatio * image.Width) / 100);
}
```

So, what that means is that, if you don't want to compute the height value yourself, just pass in a height value that is very large.

```
image.Resize(800, 100000, true, true);
```

This will cause `hRatio` to be larger than `wRatio` and then `height` will be computed based on `width`.

Since you have `preventEnlarge` set to `true`, you could just pass `image.Height` in.

```
image.Resize(800, image.Height, true, true);
```

Of course, it's not difficult to just compute `height` yourself:

```
int width = 800;
int height = (int)Math.Round(((width * 1.0) / image.Width) * image.Height);
image.Resize(width, height, false, true);
```

Comment: Yea, why is that height thing so stupid. You should be able to pass null into it! Oh well.. Who on earth made it lol?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution applicable for Winform

---

Using this function :

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth)
{    
    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, image.Height);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, image.Height);
    return newImage;
}
```

Usage :

```
Image resized_image = ScaleImage(image, 800);
```